# Reportlab pdf encoding

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab, linux-mint

I want to write some Turkish character to pdf with reportlab.
i used fallowing code to do this.

```
c = Canvas("test.pdf")  
data="ğçİöşü"
p = Paragraph(data.decode('utf-8'), style=styNormal)
```

but it doesn’t show my data at pdf.

ouput:
 ■ç■ö■ü

Answer (score 6):

As explained in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17011377/389289), you need to use a font which supports your characters.

In short, try this:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Verdana', 'Verdana.ttf'))
c.setFont("Verdana", 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is UTF-8 encoded and I'd also recommend making sure the data variable is UTF-8 by doing

```
data = u"ğçİöşü"
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your answer but i already tried make utf-8 to text. I couldn’t understand what you mean with making file utf-8 (Is it about file/save as>with(utf-8)).

Comment: yes, make sure the file is saved in utf8. alternatively, you can live with any encoding where the lower 7 bits match ASCII if you're willing to use escape codes for all non-ASCII characters (like \u0123)