# Django reportlab latin2 encoding

Tags: python, django, encoding, reportlab, iso-8859-2

is there any option to convert latin2 letters in a proper way? I need polish letter to my school project. Here is some code how I generate pdf

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4



def GenerujPustyArkusz(c):
    c.setFont("Times-Roman", 8)
    c.drawString(450,750, u"Załącznik nr 2 do Regulaminu")


def test():
    c = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf", pagesize=letter)
    GenerujPustyArkusz(c)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()


test()
```

And I get this:

```
Za■■cznik nr 2 do Regulaminu
```

I tried several encoding tricks with no result.

Comment: Where are you getting that wrong output? In the generated pdf?

Comment: Yes, this what I get is copied from pdf (I replaced copied 'nn' with black squares - this is what I see in pdf).

Comment: Try this line in `GenerujPustyAskusz` method instead: `c.drawString(450,750, "Załącznik nr 2 do Regulaminu".decode('utf-8'))` also, why are you tagging this questions as latin2, I think you're using utf-8?

Comment: Letters I need are latin2 (iso-8859-2) like łóżźćńś. I tried this trick with no result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the main problem is that the font you're using doesn't have those polish characters.
This code worked for me and showed up the characters you wanted:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont   

def GenerujPustyArkusz(c):
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Verdana', 'Verdana.ttf'))
    c.setFont("Verdana", 8)
    s = u"Załącznik nr 2 do Regulaminu"
    c.drawString(450,750, s)   

def test():
    c = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf", pagesize=letter)
    GenerujPustyArkusz(c)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()  

test()
```

If you want to use other font you'll have to find the typeface you want that include the polish characters.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awosome! It works. Thanks a lot, u saved me a lot of time. SOLVED

Comment: I´m glad, consider accepting the answer please if it was useful to you please :)